# Solve for the X/Y (Cartesian) coordinates of the remaining vertices of an isosceles triangle with known Angles & Lengths

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I'm attempting to program something and I'm reaching the limits of what I can remember about basic geometry (its been like 15 years since I've taken trig).  I feel like I have figured out a large chunk of the problem but I'm struggling with the final triangle equations.  I've tried googling but I'm having trouble coming down to the solution because google's info on isoceles triangles aren't described in cartesian form.  Here is what I got.

Imagine a circle centered on the point (135, 135).  The circle has a radius of 125.  This circle is divided into 24 pie slices.  The first slice starts at 0 degrees off the x axis and goes to 15 degrees and the slices continue all the way around the circle filling up all 360 degrees.

https://ibb.co/GkS57vj

This part of the question isn't particularly important, but hopefully adds some context of what I am doing.

Now its the triangle part that is confusing me.  I want to generate an isosceles triangle with its vertex at a point along the circle.  I know the angle of the vertex (and therefore all the angles of the triangle) and I know the lengths of all the sides of the triangle.  And I also know how to generate the X and Y coordinates of the vertex of the triangle using trig as shown below.

https://ibb.co/pjzxy1M

So the X coordinate of the point on the circle is 135 + (125 * cosθ)

The Y coordinate of the point on the circle is 135 - (125 * sinθ)

The lengths of the sides of the triangle are 10, 10, & 12

The vertex angle of the isosceles triangle is the arccos(1 - 144/200)

Based on my googling, if I set the angle I'm inputting to 90 degrees or pi/2 radians, i can determine the location of the all the points using the idea that lengths of multiples of 5, 5, & 6 make a triangle that works.  Therefore at 90 degrees, the vertices of the triangle would be at A(135,10), B(129,2), and C(141,2).  But I don't know how to produce a formula that produces B's & C's X and Y coordinates.  I hope that makes sense.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not think that the isosceles triangles you are generating would be unique; ie there would be more than 1 triangle that have given side lengths, given vertex angle, and given one vertex. 

Consider when A is origin, then you have atleast 4 such triangles. Also how do these triangles connect to the circle you used as context?

Comment: The more I think about it, I tend to believe you are correct that multiple isoscoles triangles could be generated.  The particular isosceles triangle I am trying to generate at any given point of the circle is the same triangle as the one created at 90 degrees: A(135,10), B(129,2) and C(141.2).

The triangles connect to the circle in that one point of the triangle is always on the circle of the triangle while the other two points of the triangle have an equal angle from the circle.  Here is another picture that represents the relationship of the triangle to the circle: https://ibb.co/XCrMQqZ

Comment: Consider your example $A:(135,10)$. Why is $B:(129,2)$, $C:(141,2)$ accepted but $B:(125, 10)$ and $C:(132.2, 0.4)$ isn't? Both the triangles are essentially the same, with same angles, side lengths, etc.

Comment: OMG I just realized that way the program generates the "graph" is different than the way math does it.  So those numbers are incorrect (sorry!).  Assuming the circle is centered at point (135,-135) and has a radius of 125.  Using a θ of pi/2 would give you the points A : (135, -10), B : (129, -2), and C : (141, -2).  I'm going to try updating the post with those corrections.

Comment: I do not think it matters what quadrant the circle lies in! The formulae in my answer still hold. What is bothering me is the same, since there are n number of triangles that satisfy the given constraints, why did you accept the one you did and not others??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not provide a closed form for the coordinates but some formulae that you can use.

The distance formula can be the first step here.

$$10=\sqrt{(Ax-Bx)^2+(Ay-By)^2}$$
$$10=\sqrt{(Ax-Cx)^2+(Ay-Cy)^2}$$
$$12 = \sqrt{(Bx-Cx)^2 + (By - Cy)^2}$$
Secondly, the angle between the two lines $|AC|$ and $|AB|$ you have given to be $a$ such that $cos \ \ a= 1-\frac{144}{200}$
Now I define

$$m_1 = \frac{Ay - By}{Ax-Bx} \\ m_2 = \frac{Ay-Cy}{Ax-Cx}$$ then I also have the condition:

$$
| \frac{m_1 - m_2}{1+m_1m_2} | = tan(cos^{-1}(1 - \frac{144}{200}))
$$ where $|x|$ is the absolute value of $x$.

Now unfortunately I do not have access to any computer resource that can let me use these equations to find a closed form for $Bx$, $By$, $Cx$, and $Cy$. Maybe you can try to use these equations and put them to a CAS to try to get closed expressions for the same?

After determining $A$, you can click [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=X+%3D+0%5C%2844%29+Y+%3D+0+%5C%2844%29+++10+%3D+Sqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29X-x%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D+%2B+Power%5B%5C%2840%29Y-y%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2844%29+10+%3D+Sqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29X-p%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D+%2B+Power%5B%5C%2840%29Y-q%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2844%29+12%3DSqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29x-p%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D+%2B+Power%5B%5C%2840%29y-q%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2844%29+Abs%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Y+-+q%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29X+-p%5C%2841%29%5D+-+Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Y-y%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29X-x%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2C1+%2B+Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Y-q%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29Y-y%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29X-p%5C%2841%29%5C%2840%29X-x%5C%2841%29%5D%5D%5D%3Dtan%5C%2840%29arccos%5C%2840%291+-+Divide%5B144%2C200%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29) and put the coordinates of $A$ with the scheme ($Ax = X$, $Ay = Y$, $Bx = x$, $By = y$, $Cx = p$, $Cy = q$) to find triangles that pass through $A$ satisfying the given constraints.

Comment: I'm looking over this answer now, thinking about it, seeing if it answers my question and I can derive the formulas I need.  I'll mark it as solved if it works.  Added more info as a response to your comment if that helps clarify.  I appreciate the help

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm still confused by the framing of the question!! After you choose an appropriate value of $\theta$, you get some coordinates for $A$. Then from there you can choose from (I suppose infinite) number of triangles, and these formulae can work only to find the possible values of the coordinates. Consider when $\theta = 90^\circ$, why did you choose only B:(129,2), C:(141,2) while there are many other possible triangles also??